# Error when trying to create spatial points variable when creating a home range

Tags: r

I am trying to create spatial points variables so R recognises the columns as geographic coordinates. The code and the error message are shown below. I think it could be related to the fact that my coordinates are Easting & Northing Coordinates WGS 84 instead of the usual long/lat? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> elephant.all.sp<-SpatialPoints(elephant[c(GPS.E,GPS.S)])
> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'coordinates': undefined columns selected

> elephant.all.sp<-SpatialPoints(elephant[c(GPS.S,GPS.E),])
> Error in .local(obj, ...) :
> cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example of your data? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some advice on creating reproducible examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eastings and Northings should not be a problem, R should understand every format. It seems you have two errors. In the first line your are missing quotes:

```
elephant.all.sp<-SpatialPoints(elephant[c("GPS.E","GPS.S")])
```

Using the bracket notation to extract from a data.frame requires a text vector. Unquoted only works when using `$`, e.g. `elephant$GPS.E`.

On the second line you are getting a coercion error. R is understanding that you are giving SpatialPoints() a matrix filled with text, which it does not understand how it could be turned into numbers and then coordinates. This is most likely because you calling the *rows* "GPS.E" and "GPS.S" and not columns. This is because you placed the `c("GPS.E","GPS.S")` before the comma in the middle of the brackets. The correct form should be:

```
elephant.all.sp<-SpatialPoints(elephant[,c("GPS.S","GPS.E")])
```

Note that when there are no commas in the brackets, R treats the value given as column indexes (in data.frames), which makes the two lines in my answer equivalent.